# Where to put jsp project folder in tomcat for hosting?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat6, host

I am right now working with JSP and using tomcat Apache for that.what my problem is when i am creating one single JSP page and putting in root directory of tomcat then its working fine.but now i have one project that contains some useful jars and other java classes so how to put that whole project directory in tomcat.

I had put that in web app directory but its giving me error as follows

```
The requested resource (/dailymotion-cloudkey-java-73f6f35/examples/upload.jsp) is not available.
```

I am Giving snapshot of my web app folder where i had put this folder name as dailymotion-cloudkey-java-73f6f35

[image]

i know that i am doing mistake while putting dailymotion-cloudkey-java-73f6f35 directory in tomcat.
but i am totally new in this so i couldn't find out so can anyone tell me

tree Structure of my project
[image]

Comment: Move/copy your project into webapps (`auto-deploy` folder).

Comment: can you please explain?i cant understand with the (auto-deploy folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think dailymotion-cloudkey-java-73f6f35, does not have WEB-INF folder with web.xml file. Due to which it is not able to locate the resources.

or

You can copy your dailymotion-cloudkey-java-73f6f35 project directory into ROOT folder and then try the same URL.

Comment: do you have tomcat manager war deployed. if yes, then please check whether your application is running through that

Comment: does your project folder has WEB-INF and web.xml file ? Please share tree explorer screenshot of your deployed project.

Comment: just see my question.i have given tree structure there

Comment: That not Tree structure. Tree structure means on left side of your screen shot, with all folders inside your project folder should be collase all.

Comment: OK.i have imported that whole project in eclipse and giving you the tree structure again .please refer it from my updated question and guide me

Comment: One thing I want to Add is i can run this upload.jsp and other jsp file in eclipse on tomcat server but its cant run from the browser independently when i manually start tomcat server and give url in browser like http://localhost:8080/DailyMotion/MediaList.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Put it anywhere, but put a context file for your webapp to TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost which points to for webapps's directory with the docbase attribute. Read details [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).